# Reverse proxy through Apache with Docker GitLab

Tags: apache, docker, gitlab

I have set up the following `VirtualHost` in my `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyRequests On
 ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /gitlab http://190.22.22.40:6060/gitlab
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://190.22.22.40:6060/gitlab
</VirtualHost>
```

**EXPECTED**

When I try to load the URL, `http://190.22.22.40/gitlab`, I want to go to the actual GitLab page to sign in as a new user

**ACTUAL**

I am redirected to a blank page with the url `http://190.22.22.40/users/sign_in`

**QUESTION**

How can I go to the login page with the URL `http://190.22.22.40/gitlab` and **NO** port specified in the URL?

Comment: ip address which you access gitlab from uotside must be different from ip address of  gitlab docker container.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan If the IP is not set to the gitlab docker container, what should it be set to?

Comment: you can find ip address of docker using `docker inspect container_id`

Comment: I have the answer but I will not write here since this is a question for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). Create a new question there and I will post the answer. Unfortunately I can't ask for migration because the question is too old.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab do not use context to separate multiple application as there is only one.

You need to proxy pass "/" and not "/gitlab"  eg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyRequests On
 ProxyPreserveHost On

 ProxyPass / http://190.22.22.40:6060/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Would this be the same for the `ProxyPassReverse?`

Comment: ProxyPreserveHost make the use of ProxyPassReverse not useful. Note that gitlab.rb should also reference the host gitlab should respond to. (there is 2 in fact, one for http(s) one for ssh, which can be the same or not)

Comment: is `gitlab.rb` inside the Docker container?